# Inject dll, and call procedure from this dll

Tags: delphi, winapi, dll

inject dll in another process has turned out, but still need to call the function in this dll, how to implement it?
But more particularly, after inject in the process, i'm need to call setHWND function for send values, from my app to injected process...

slice dll

```
 procedure Init(Reason: integer);
    begin
      Dll_reason := Reason;
      HookPoint_Address := 0;
      if (Reason = DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH) then
      begin
        ShowMessage('Прикрепились');
        InitHook;
      end;
    end;

    procedure setHWND(hwnd: Cardinal);
    begin
     hwnd_param:=hwnd;
    end;

    exports
      setHWND;

    begin
      DLLProc := Init;
      Init(DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH);
```

slice injector

```
function InjectDLL(dwPID: DWORD; DLLPath: PWideChar): integer;
var
  dwThreadID: Cardinal;
  hProc, hThread, hKernel: THandle;
  BytesToWrite, BytesWritten: SIZE_T;
  pRemoteBuffer, pLoadLibrary: Pointer;
begin
  hProc := OpenProcess(PROCESS_CREATE_THREAD or PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION or
    PROCESS_VM_OPERATION or PROCESS_VM_WRITE or PROCESS_VM_READ, False, dwPID);
  if hProc = 0 then
    exit(0);
  try
    BytesToWrite := SizeOf(WideChar) * (Length(DLLPath) + 1);
    pRemoteBuffer := VirtualAllocEx(hProc, nil, BytesToWrite, MEM_COMMIT,
      PAGE_READWRITE);
    if pRemoteBuffer = nil then
      exit(0);
    try
      if not WriteProcessMemory(hProc, pRemoteBuffer, DLLPath, BytesToWrite,
        BytesWritten) then
        exit(0);
      hKernel := GetModuleHandle('kernel32.dll');
      pLoadLibrary := GetProcAddress(hKernel, 'LoadLibraryW');
      hThread := CreateRemoteThread(hProc, nil, 0, pLoadLibrary, pRemoteBuffer,
        0, dwThreadID);
      try
        WaitForSingleObject(hThread, INFINITE);
      finally
        CloseHandle(hThread);
      end;
    finally
      VirtualFreeEx(hProc, pRemoteBuffer, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
    end;
  finally
    CloseHandle(hProc);
  end;
  exit(1);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  PID: DWORD;
  dir: string;
begin
  SetSeDebugPrivilege;
  PID := GetPID('zorron.exe');
  if (PID > 0) then
  begin
    dir := GetCurrentDir;
    InjectDLL(PID, PWideChar(dir + '\trans.dll'));
  end;

end;
```

Thx

Comment: Don't show UI in DllMain. Call CreateThread and do the work there.

Comment: i,m need call setHWND from main app

Comment: Well, do that. But not from DllMain. As covered by the docs. Call CreateThread in DllMain to do the work.

Answer (score 0):

As has been explained in the old/new thing. You cannot do real work in the DllMain function.
If you do this and the app stops whilst you're busy in DllMain the app will deadlock.
Lots of other activities in DllMain can also cause a deadlock, see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn633971%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

So that's why you create a new thread **Using `CreateThread`**
Just remember to not synchronize your thread because that will cause a deadlock.  As long as you don't synchronize you are golden.

After you've injected the dll, you start a new thread, like so:

```
procedure DoWorkInDLL(data: pointer): bool; stdcall;
begin
  ...
end;

procedure EntryPoint(Reason: dword);
var
  ThreadID: cardinal;
begin
  if Reason = DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH then begin
    Win32Check(CreateThread(nil,0, @Main, nil, 0, ThreadId));
  end;
  Assert(ThreadID <> 0);
end;


begin
  DLLProc:= @EntryPoint;
  EntryPoint(DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH);
end.
```

I now the docs so don't use `CreateThread` but it's really only the synchronization issues that are the problem.
The issue here is that normally an application initiates the dll, however when you inject a dll, that is never the case and therefore you have to adjust your point of reference.
Inside the `DoWork` function you can call the `SetHWnd`, because you're now detached from the dll-loading and the risk of deadlocks, however you still cannot call synchronize inside your thread.
If you want to synchronize, you'll have to create another thread and synchronize there.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to export setHWND(), make sure you use stdcall directive

```
procedure setHWND(hwnd: Cardinal); stdcall;
begin
 hwnd_param:=hwnd;
end;
```

to make use Windows calling convention.